# Why does an object with redefined __getattr__() throws TypeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, setattr

Here is the code

```
class MyTest: 
    def __init__(self):
         pass

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        pass
t = MyTest()
print 'my test object: %r' %t
```

So print triggers a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` while i only want to see if object exists.
Granted this code isn't very useful.  But i've had a stub class like that in a big code base so i did

```
if module and module.class and module.class.propery:
   # do something with that property
 ...
```

and got a `Type Error: 'NoneType' object is not callable` but the line doesn't call anything!  I guess python is calling some functions implicitly behind the scenes.

Curiously this doesn't happen if the class inherits from `Object`

What's going on?

Comment: `__getattr__` should return something, not `None`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Discrimination! `None` *is* "something"!

Comment: Your string formatting operation tries to access the `__repr__` attribute of  `t`, and since you are using an old-style class (you didn't inherit from `object`), `__getattr__` is returning `None` instead of actually returning the required method to call. Don't use old-style classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an old-style class, `__getattr__` is used for a greater variety of attribute access, including magic methods. The `%` operator is trying to call `t.__repr__()` in order to fill in the `%r` placeholder, but `t.__repr__` is evaluated by `t.__getattr__('__repr__')`, which returns `None`.

In the `if` case, a different magic method is invoked, but the same problem occurs.

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __getattr__(self, attr):
...     print(attr)
...
>>> f = Foo():
>>> if f:
...   pass
__nonzero__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Use a new-style class, `__getattr__` is only invoked if an attribute cannot be found via the normal method (checking the `__dict__` attribute of the instance or of any of the class's in the instance's MRO).

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.x = 3
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         print(attr)
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> if f:
...   pass
...
>>> f.x
3
>>> f.y
y
```

In the `if f` case, `f` itself doesn't implement `__nonzero__` or `__len__`, and neither does its parent `object`, but in that case, no attribute is used; the fact that `f` is, in fact, an object is used. In `f.x`, `x` is found in the instance's attribute dict, so its value is returned directly. Only `y`, which isn't otherwise defined by `f`, `Foo`, or `object`, invokes a call to `__getattr__`.

Comment: so ` if t` also calls `__repr__()` ?

Comment: No, but evaluating `t` in a Boolean context will call something. Using Jean-François Fabre's suggestion of printing the argument to `__getattr__` before returning anything should show that `t.__nonzero__` is called to determine if `t` is truthy or not.

Answer (score 2):

In python 2, with old-style classes, when you try to call `__repr__` (when printing) on an object, you have `__getattr__` called.

Since you violently stubbed this method, it returns `None` and python tries to call `None` (because it's expecting a method to be returned)

Try to call `object.__getattr__` instead, that'll work:

```
class MyTest:
    def __init__(self):
         pass

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print(attr)   # so we see why getattr is called
        return object.__getattr__(self,attr)  # so it doesn't crash (neither it is useful...)

t = MyTest()
print ('my test object: %r' %t)
```

prints:

```
__repr__
my test object: <__main__.MyTest instance at 0x00000000031B3808>
```

this is a specific python 2/old-style object issue. Python 3 or new-style objects don't behave the same